# Change GeoRSS Style based on attributes - ESRI ArcGIS Maps SDK for Javascript

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I have successfully implemented the solution to a question relating to accessing a GeoRSS's attributes using the code here:

[Access GeoRSS Attributes using ESRI ArcGIS Maps SDK for JavaScript](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/463567/access-georss-attributes-using-esri-arcgis-maps-sdk-for-javascript)

My current code pulls in coordinates from a GeoRSS, creates a new graphic polygon using these coordinates and then counts the number of features located within the Graphic.

I am now looking to use the attributes in this feed to style the points and polygons in feed based on one of these attributes. The style does not need to be a fancy picture marker for the points, a simple square with varying colours is what I am after.

A subset of my code is as follows:

```
       const layer = new GeoRSSLayer({
                    url: "https://www.rfs.nsw.gov.au/feeds/majorIncidents.xml"                      
                    });

        webmap.add(layer);
        console.log (layer)
        layer.on("layerview-create", function(event){
          layer.featureCollections.forEach(function(collection) {
            console.log('collection: ', collection.name);
            if (collection.name === 'Polygons'){
            console.log(collection)
            }
            else if (collection.name === 'Points'){
                collection.featureSet.features.forEach(function(feature) {
              console.log('feature: ', feature.attributes.category , feature.geometry);
              }
```

How can I use the **feature.attributes.category** to style the points / polygon in my feed?